# Linear Gradient Not working for rounded touchable opacity React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, linear-gradients

[image: button gradient]

I created a Linear gradient for my touchable opacity. The issue is i want my button to be rounded so i added "borderRadius: 100" and the gradient, covers where the "corners" would be if i didnt round the button. How do i get rid of this? Below is my code and image of the issue. I looked everywhere and can't seem to find the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <View
          style={{
            flex: 0.6,
            justifyContent: "flex-start",
          }}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            colors={[
              "#F7BBB2",
              "#FFC9B5",
              "#FFDDC7",
              "#FFF6D4",
              "#FFFDF2",
            ]}
            // style={styles.background}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
              disabled={isDisabled}
              style={
                isDisabled
                  ? styles.disabled
                  : styles.btnContainer
              }
              //activeOpacity={0.2}
              onPress={() => {
                //handleSignUp();
                pressHandler();
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: "black",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                  //opacity: 0.3,
                }}
              >
                Next
                <Text>{"  "}</Text>
                <Ionicons
                  name="arrow-forward-outline"
                  size={20}
                  color="black"
                />
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </LinearGradient>
        </View>
```

Here is my style for the button

```
disabled: {
    width: 200,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 100,
    overflow: "hidden",
    borderWidth: 1,

  },
```

Comment: give same border radius to LinearGradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with

```
  <LinearGradient
    colors={[
      "#F7BBB2",
      "#FFC9B5",
      "#FFDDC7",
      "#FFF6D4",
      "#FFFDF2",
    ]}
    style={{borderRadius: 100}}
    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
  >
```

Or just add this `style = {{borderRadius : 100}}` to your `<LinearGradient >` component.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately When i added it, the button looks like an oval more than just rounded corners

Comment: when i changed borderRadius: 20 it works, 100 condensed it, thanks!